# How can I ignore a gem source on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I have a Rails app with some private gems used for testing locally; I do not need to access them in production, on Heroku. They are loaded in the gemfile as source block, e.g:

```
group :development, :test do
  source "https://myprivaterepo" do
    gem "mycustomgem", "~> 1.0"
  end
end
```

When I try to deploy to Heroku, the build fails ('could not fetch specs from https://myprivaterepo') because Heroku cannot access the gem source. I have set a BUNDLE_WITHOUT config var to ignore development and test gems, but this still doesn't prevent the build trying to fetch gems from this source. How can I prevent this, so that Heroku just ignores these gems and their source completely?

Using Ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.2, Heroku-16 stack.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test"`

or

`gem 'mycustomgem', source: "https://myprivaterepo.com" if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'production'`

Comment: Thanks, I have added a config variable and this is being applied - when I run `git push heroku master` I can see in the output `running: bundle install --without development:test`, but it doesn't solve the problem that the build then fails because it cannot fetch these gems from the source.

Comment: Finally, I tested with contidion you have source(host) wich not reach from production and it is works